# Proof regarding expectations

Tags: probability

Let $Y$ be random variable with continuous distribution and density as $G(Y)$ and $g(y)$ respectively.

The question is, how do I prove that $E[Y|Y<k]=\frac{ \displaystyle\int_0^k y\,g(y)\,dy}{\displaystyle G(k)}$? I am not much familiar with measure theory, so a non measure theoretic argument will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(Y\leq t|Y<k)=P(Y\leq t,Y<k)/P(Y<k)$
$$=\begin{cases}
P(Y\leq t)/P(Y<k),  & \text{for $t<k$} \\
1, & \text{for $t\geq k.$}
\end{cases}$$

Hence density of $Y|Y<k$ is $g(t)/G(k)$ for $t<k$ and equal to $0$ otherwise. Hence $$E(Y|Y<k)=\frac1{G(k)}\int_{-\infty}^kyg(y)dy.$$